# sum of Maclaurin series c++

Tags: c++, sum

I am struggling to make this equation equals to each other because of a bad understanding of mathematics.

The problem is that the equation does not equal to each other
here is my code for better understand

[image]

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <ccomplex>

using std::cout;

int main() {
    int n = 8;
    double sum = 0.0;
    unsigned long long fact =1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        fact *= 2*i*(2*i-1);
        sum += 1.0 / fact;
    }
    std::cout << "first equation " << sum << std::endl;


    double e = M_E;
    double st = 1.0/2.0*(e + (1.0/e));
    std::cout <<"second equation " << st << std::endl;



    return 0;
}
```

the output

```
first equation 0.543081
second equation 1.54308
```

The result it nearly It must be at least equal before the comma,

Answer (score 4):

You don't account for `n = 0`, which yields `0!` and thus `1`. Therefore, you need to add `1` to `sum`.